# Grouping items in XML

Tags: xml

I'm trying to store some information using XML, what would be the correct method for grouping the data?
I have multiple computers in three rooms, should I create a room element or use an attribute?

```
<rooms>
<room name="Room 1">
  <computer>
    <name>Student14</name>
    <ipaddress>00.00.00.01</ipaddress>
    <macaddress>00-0B-DB-74-12-AB</macaddress>
  </computer>
 </room>
<room name="Room 2">
  <computer>
    <name>Student15</name>
    <ipaddress>00.00.00.02</ipaddress>
    <macaddress>00-0B-DB-74-12-AC</macaddress>
  </computer>
 </room>
<room name="Room 3">
  <computer>
    <name>Student16</name>
    <ipaddress>00.00.00.03</ipaddress>
    <macaddress>00-0B-DB-74-12-AD</macaddress>
  </computer>
 </room>
</rooms>
```

Or like this:

```
<computers>
  <computer>
    <name>Student14</name>
    <ipaddress>00.00.00.01</ipaddress>
    <macaddress>00-0B-DB-74-00-AC</macaddress>
    <location>Room 1</location>
  </computer>
  <computer>
    <name>Student15</name>
    <ipaddress>00.00.00.02</ipaddress>
    <macaddress>00-0B-DB-74-00-AB</macaddress>
    <location>Room 2</location>
  </computer>
  <computer>
    <name>Student16</name>
    <ipaddress>00.00.00.03</ipaddress>
    <macaddress>00-0B-DB-74-00-AD</macaddress>
    <location>Room 3</location>
  </computer>
</computers>
```

Comment: I'd seriously look at using a relational database to store the data. From it you can generate whatever XML views are needed (e.g. depending on if the use case requires grouping by room or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what data you are concerned with. Do you want to store information about rooms or computers? In your first example, you are storing information about rooms. This could also include couches, lamps, etc. In your second, you are storing information about computers. This could include their location, model, etc.

It depends on what you want the information to be about.

Comment: I want to store information about computers. I have a drag and drop GUI for moving computers between rooms. A treeview is expanded for each room with a list of computers under each. I assumed the computers should be nested inside rooms (maintain hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" representation. There's no such thing as a "normal form" for XML, as there is with relational databases. Generally, the objects in your system will form a general graph, and your XML needs to be some hierarchical projection of that graph. Choose your representation for convenience, and be prepared to transform from one representation to another.

(MusicXML, for example, defines two representations, one in which events in the timeline are at the top level, and the other in which instrumental or vocal parts are at the top level. The two representations are equivalent, and are useful for different purposes.)